# Add 6 months to Moment Date and populate field in each loop

Tags: jquery, date, momentjs

I have a date created as a moment object, in this case it is `15 Jan 2015` and I have a set of input fields which have a class of `periodDate` what I need to do is add 6 months to the source date and populate the input with the value.

`#periodDate1` is populated with `17 Dec 2014` and `#periodDate2` has the `moment_next_coupon_date` as the value.

```
var moment_next_coupon_date = moment('15 Jan 2015');

$(_clsPeriodDate).each(function() {
    $(this).not("#periodDate1").not('#periodDate2').val(moment_next_coupon_date.add(6, 'M').format('DD MMM YYYY'));
});
```

This is kind of working but the dates jump from 2015 to 2016 for example the next two dates outputted are `15 Jul 2016` and `15 Jan 2017` from which point it starts to work and increments the date but 6 months as expected.

Can anyone tell me why this is happening and what do to sort it out?

Comment: Can you create a snippet here, or a jsfiddle which demonstrates the problem? ([Here's a blank jsfiddle with momentjs and jquery](http://jsfiddle.net/to5t868d/))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens because you call `add` on your moment object regardless of whether your `.not` conditions are met; just because the jQuery set you're calling `val` on may be empty, that doesn't mean that the expression you're passing into `val` isn't evaluated. And since moment objects mutate...

A much simpler and more direct approach would be to simply use `if`:

```
var moment_next_coupon_date = moment('15 Jan 2015');

$(_clsPeriodDate).each(function() {
    if (this.id !== "periodDate1" && this.id !== "periodDate2") {
        $(this).val(moment_next_coupon_date.add(6, 'M').format('DD MMM YYYY'));
    }
});
```

...or to filter them out earlier:

```
var moment_next_coupon_date = moment('15 Jan 2015');

$(_clsPeriodDate).not("#periodDate1, #periodDate2").each(function() {
    $(this).val(moment_next_coupon_date.add(6, 'M').format('DD MMM YYYY'));
});
```

Comment: Perfect, it makes perfect sense, thanks for helping a dummy out ;)